# Как реализовать Socks5 сервер?

Tags: c#, socks5

Не могу найти документацию как реализовать Sosks5 сервер, нашел много теории по этой теме, но нигде нету информации какими библиотеками это реализовать или где найти инфу по реализации. Может кто подсказать?

Comment: Никакие библиотеки не нужны. Все можно сделать стандартными средствами.

Comment: @Zergatul, А можно по точнее как? Это же не просто написать TCP-сервер

Comment: Вообще надо как раз знать немного теории про TCP и почитать про сам протокол. TCP-сервера как раз пишутся просто. И кстати в интернете куча исходников готовых sock5 серверов на любых языках. Берите, изуайте

Comment: @Mike, Не нашел не одного примера реализации сервера на Socks5. Есть очень очень много примеров реализации прокси, но вот  сервера не нашел. Были примеры просто tcp сервера, без socks5

Comment: Эммм ...А что такое "Socks5 сервер" ? Socks5 это протокол проксирования, в протоколе заложен максимум десяток  команд, все из которых нацелены на одно: принять соединение от клиента, соединится с каким нибудь еще адресом и передавать трафик между клиентом и той точкой. Ни для чего другого данный протокол использоваться не может. Так что любой Socks5 сервер - это как раз прокси. Максимум что можно сделать - это не соединятся с другой стороной, а эмулировать ее ответы самому, как будто соеденились

Comment: @Mike, я имел ввиду прием и обработка пакета.

Comment: А чем вас код готовых прокси серверов не устроил. Там всегда есть функция, которая принимает пакет и его обрабатывает

Comment: @Mike, Тем что я ищу не готовое решение, где я ничего не смогу изменить и не смогу посмотреть как оно реализовано. А хотя бы скрипт где показано как это происходит.

Comment: Я же говорю, что полно исходников, берете эти исходники, смотрите как что происходит и правите как вам понравится. Вот первое что дал гугл по запросу "C# Socks5 server source code" https://github.com/ThrDev/Socks5/tree/master/socks5

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо большое.